# How can I display a list of categories of my posts

Tags: categories, link-category

I have a Post Category called 'Podcasts' and under it are many other sub-categories.

On a page I have titled "Podcast Categories", I would like to list all categories under the "Podcasts" category, as links to their category page. I'm fairly new to Wordpress, what would be the best way of accomplishing this?

Thank you very much!

Note: I do not want to display any kind of post content on this page, only the category name as a link. When I do google searching, I'm finding lots of info on how to post content from these categories.

UPDATE 1:

page-podcast-list.php

```
          <div id="content">
            <?php          
              $cat = get_category_by_slug( 'podcasts' );
              $catid = $cat->ID;
            ?>
            <?php
              wp_list_categories( array(
                'child_of' => $catid;
              ) );
            ?>
          </div><!-- /content -->
```

This isn't doing what I expected. It's printing out:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in /path/to/page-podcast-list.php on line 49

I'm not sure what line 49 is specifically at the moment, since I'm using the Built in WordPress Editor, without line numbers unfortunately..

I'm not familiar with php for the record, but am familiar with basic programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `wp_list_categories()` ([Codex ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories)), using the `child_of` argument.

Assuming you know the ID of the "Podcasts" category, e.g. `123`:

```
wp_list_categories( array(
    'child_of' => '123'
) );
```

If you need to find the category ID, use `get_category_by_slug` ([Codex ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_by_slug)):

```
$cat = get_category_by_slug( 'podcasts' );
$catid = $cat->ID;

wp_list_categories( array(
    'child_of' => $catid
) );
```

Rather than executing PHP from within the Page content, I would simply [create a custom Page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates):

1. Copy `page.php` as `page-podcast-list.php`
2. At the top of `page-podcast-list.php` put the following:

.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Podcast List
*/
?>
```

1. Look for the post content markup (e.g. `<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <php post_class(); ?>>`), and replace what's inside it (should include `<?php the_content(); ?>`, etc.) with the `$wp_list_categories()` code from above.

If you have problems, copy/paste the code from `page-podcast-list.php` in your answer, and we'll help from there.

**EDIT 2**

Your parse error is here, inside of your `wp_list_categories()` argument array:

```
'child_of' => $catid;
```

Should instead be:

```
'child_of' => $catid
```

(no semicolon)

Comment: I marked it as answer too soon. I think I have the page-podcast-list.php setup, but what do I now put into the page content? I'm not sure how to call the wp_list_categories from the page.

Comment: Can you clarify better what it is you're trying to do? I understood your question to mean that you wanted to have a static Page that listed links to Podcast categories. Is that not correct?

Comment: That is correct. I'm not sure how to specify that my page needs to use the page-podcast-list.php.

Comment: I just discovered I needed to add:

/*
Template Name: The Name of This Template
*/

To the top of my template.

Comment: Ahh, yeah; I had that in my answer, but the code block didn't print properly. :)

Comment: Please see my UPDATE 1 in my question.

Comment: Answer updated with parse error fix